# R Shiny App on an iPad in Internet Denied Locations

Tags: r, react-native, shiny, electron

I currently have a number of Shiny Apps that I've developed that I'm looking to deploy on different platforms.  I'm struggling with the problem of deploying a Shiny App (or some derivative of it) to an iPad that does not have internet access.  Although it is possible to create a separate app for this purpose, most likely with React-Native, I'm trying to find a way to recycle as much code as possible.

Thus far, I've explored using tools to run the Shiny App as an electron application using R Shiny Electron (https://github.com/dirkschumacher/r-shiny-electron).  More background is provided here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ARrbbviGvjc .

I was successfully able to use this tool to run my app with Electron but I realize that running Electron on an iPad is not feasible.  I was hoping to salvage some JS used in this electron process in a react native app but I haven't found a way to do that yet either.

Does anyone have some insights as to how I could convert the electron app to React-Native without starting from scratch or at least use some of the Shiny code (preferably UI components) in a way that can be run on an iPad?

Comment: It's not clear to me ... is there some form of R-shiny serving process within network-range of the iPad, but neither has internet access? Or are you trying to get an iPad (and only an iPad, no external resources) to run a shiny app?

Comment: @r2evans    I currently run the apps using R-Shiny Server and when internet access is available, I am able to access them from an iPad with no issues.  I'm interested in finding a way to run these apps locally on an iPad so that the applications can be used in internet denied environments.  I realize that directly running a Shiny App on an iPad is really only possible if its Jailbroken.  I am trying to find a way to convert my Shiny App into a form that can be run on iPad by reusing as much code as possible.

Comment: I don't think it's "easy" to convert a shiny app to run unaccompanied on an iPad. There are several apps on the apple appstore that allege running R natively (no net connection) (e.g., https://apps.apple.com/us/app/r-analyst/id1173749340?mt=8), though I have no experience with them. At least one other claimed to be only a compiler that does not support interactive R scripts, so a lot of research might be required. And it looks like the better ones are not free.

Comment: @r2evans There are 2 apps from the same author that claim to allow for running R natively and I have tried to use both of them.  Unfortunately, they are both severely lacking from a library support standpoint.  It's okay if the solution is very difficult to execute, I'm just trying to find a path forward.

Comment: @MaxFeinberg, which apps were these? Thanks! I've been trying to do the same with no luck. I've yet to try Analyst.

Comment: @Dania , neither app will run a shiny app. They also require internet connectivity to interact with R. I have had success using shinyapps deployed to the web on mobile though. I’ve also resorted compiling a shiny app to an electron executable for use on desktops/laptops without internet.